# Magento duplicate content issue with multistore

Tags: multistore, seo, page-content, store-code

I have multi-store websites with store code enable in URL. As google will consider the product content as duplicate on case of multi-store with store code for same product.How can I resolve this issue ? Store code must required for multi-store.

Is there any way that there is store code enable from admin but on frontend without store code product will load with that particular store ?

Answer (score 0):

exactly for this case it's recommended to you `<link>` Tag with the `hreflang` Attribute.

It should look like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-fr" href="http://example.fr/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-de" href="http://example.de/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-en" href="http://example.co.uk" />
```

Unfortunately there is no core feature to enable it, but there are a lot of module which implement this feature.